# Can Tensorflow's tf.contrib.learn be used with RNN (tf.contrib.rnn)?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

The verion of Tensorflow I am using is 1.0 . I'd like to ask, if tf.contrib.learn can be used in combined with tf.contrib.rnn?

Existing official examples([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq)) using tf.contrib.rnn all use 'basic'/'low-level' APIs to build and run the model. However, high level APIs in tf.contrib.learn produce much shorter code.  Are there examples that show tf.contrib.learn can be used with RNN (tf.contrib.rnn) ?

Tensorflow's API is constantly changing rapidly and there are not many documents that can be found on its website.